# loading CSS files dynamically in Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a windows 8 application and during my application i want to load a different CSS file based on the language of the Windows .
for example if the default language for the user is En i load a CSS file and if it is Ar i load a different one , how can i do that ?!

Comment: I think you mean the default language of the web broswer, correct? You are not going to be able to access information about the os in an HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Windows8 app still have a `<head>` right? Then you can use javascript to add css to the head.

```
var h=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var l = document.createElement("link");
l.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
l.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
l.setAttribute("href", filename);
h.appendChild(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check the default langauge for the browser ,

> ```
> var l_lang;
> if (navigator.userLanguage) // Explorer
> l_lang = navigator.userLanguage;
> else if (navigator.language) // FF   
> l_lang = navigator.language;
>
> alert(l_lang);
> ```